# Returning multiple "href"

Tags: python, tags, href

I cannot get my program to work, and I have tried for so long. Here it is, pretty simple but I cannot get it. Supposed to return anything containing "html" in it. It is really frustrating. This is for command line python 2.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

#Make this program work both on python 2.x and Python 3.x
if (sys.version_info[0] == 3): raw_input = input

import urllib2
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://makeitwork.com/')
data = url.read()
urlsearch = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'"]+)' , data)

for x in urlsearch:
    line = x.split()
    print(" %s" %line[0])
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Try [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), [*Never use regex to parse HTML code*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454?s=1|5.2446#1732454) :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urllib2.urlopen('http://makeitwork.com/')
data = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for i in soup.find_all(a):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this RegEx

```
'r'a\shref="/?(.*)">'
```

Basically searching for Anything after the `<a href` html tag and before the `>` closing statement.